# Delphi datasnap RESTful URL if contain parameter with character T/F/Y/N will convert to boolean True and False

Tags: delphi, url, rest, delphi-xe2, datasnap

I have a server method "CustomerLookup" that accept a string parameter "CompanyName", user may enter any characters and CustomerLookup method will return a list of customers that partially match the criteria. My REST URL is something like below, the final word "t" is the method's parameter

```
http://localhost/datasnap/rest/TSales_SM/CustomerLookup/t
```

My expected outcome is if user enter "t", method will return all customers' companyname that partially match "t". But i found out for certain character like T & Y will convert to True, N & F will convert to false. The converting code is implemented in delphi unit -> DataSnap.DSService

```
procedure TDSRESTService.BuildParamArray(const Params: TStringList; var ParamArray: TJSONArray);
  var
    I: Integer;
    S: String;
    LValue: Double;
  begin
    ParamArray := TJSONArray.Create;
    for I := 0 to Params.Count - 1 do
    begin
      S := Params[I];
      if (AnsiIndexText(S,TrueBoolStrs) > -1) then
         ParamArray.AddElement(TJSONTrue.Create)
      else if AnsiIndexText(S,FalseBoolStrs) > -1 then
         ParamArray.AddElement(TJSONFalse.Create)
      else if AnsiCompareStr(S,NULL) = 0 then
         ParamArray.AddElement(TJSONNull.Create)
      else
         if TDBXPlatform.TryJsonToFloat(S, LValue) then
           ParamArray.AddElement(TJSONNumber.Create(S))
         else
           ParamArray.AddElement(TJSONString.Create(S));
    end;
  end;
```

Can anyone tell me how to prevent system to convert of T, F, Y, N to true and false

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you running things you _know_ to be strings through this in the first place?

Comment: +1 just because I now know someone else is using DataSnap REST. I thought I was the only one :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there must be some where in your code define something like:

```
SetLength(TrueBoolStrs, 4);
TrueBoolStrs[0] := 'True';
TrueBoolStrs[1] := 'T';
TrueBoolStrs[2] := 'Yes';
TrueBoolStrs[3] := 'Y';

SetLength(FalseBoolStrs, 4);
FalseBoolStrs[0] := 'False';
FalseBoolStrs[1] := 'F';
FalseBoolStrs[2] := 'No';
FalseBoolStrs[3] := 'N';
```

A workaround solution would be patch TDSRestService.BuildParamArray to:

```
procedure TDSRESTService.BuildParamArrayPatch(const Params: TStringList;
  var ParamArray: TJSONArray);
const NULL = 'null';
var
  I: Integer;
  S: String;
  LValue: Double;
begin
  ParamArray := TJSONArray.Create;
  for I := 0 to Params.Count - 1 do
  begin
    S := Params[I];
    if SameText(S, 'true') then
      ParamArray.AddElement(TJSONTrue.Create)
    else if SameText(S, 'false') then
      ParamArray.AddElement(TJSONFalse.Create)
    else if AnsiCompareStr(S, NULL) = 0 then
      ParamArray.AddElement(TJSONNull.Create)
    else if TDBXPlatform.TryJsonToFloat(S, LValue) then
      ParamArray.AddElement(TJSONNumber.Create(S))
    else
      ParamArray.AddElement(TJSONString.Create(S));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The code to set the contents of `TrueBoolStrs` is in *SysUtils.pas*. You're allowed to change its contents, though, so rather than patch the library function, you could just change `TrueBoolStrs` to contain only the string `true`.

Answer (score 2):

They're converting to true and false because the code shown does exactly that. It calls `AnsiIndexText(S,TrueBoolStrs)`, and since the `TrueBoolStrs` array contains the string `T`, it matches and inserts a `TJSONTrue` object into your array. If you don't want that to happen, you'll have to avoid calling this function.

You could perform a more limited search — instead of checking all the values in the `TrueBoolStrs` array, just check for the specific values you want to be treated as Boolean values. You could do this without modifying the function by modifying the contents of `TrueBoolStrs` in advance. (It's a global variable in the SysUtils unit.) However, you'll find that you get similar problems if someone tries to search for customers with a company name that contains a numeral — it converts the argument to a `TJSONNumber`.

You're the one writing the program and defining the parameters, so if you know that a certain field name should have a certain type, then don't use a function that tries the *guess* the type when it could guess wrongly. You already know that the parameter to the `CustomerLookup` function is a string, so just convert the parameter to a `TJSONString` directly, or just use the original string without any JSON stuff at all.

If Datasnap is calling this function entirely outside your control, then you might try to find a way to access the original parameter list instead of the JSON-converted one since the latter is unreliable.

If you want the JSON-converted version, but you still also have access to the original parameter list, then another idea would be to include some form of expected type information in a custom-written conversion function based on the one shown above. Then the function can use the expected type to guide its guessing — only searching for Boolean strings if it's reading a parameter that's supposed to have a Boolean value.

Comment: I think the code in the question is in unit `DataSnap.DSService` which is automatically called. Correct me if I'm wrong though (:

Comment: I didn't realize that, @Jeroen. Thanks. I've edited to try to take that into account.

Comment: Yes DataSnap.DSService is automatically called, it is delphi code which i can't avoid

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which might be the same here.
In my Servermethod I expected several parameter which I all read in as strings:

```
TServerMethods1.InsertMember(userid, Pw, MemberName, PhoneNumber: string): TJsonArray;
```

After a while people complained that the phone number is not transfered correctly and the leading '0' was cut off.
So somewhere in the process it tries to evaluate the parameter to a type it thinks it suits! So for the phonenumber '08979' it thinks it is a number and my InsertMember function received a '8979' as phone number. I can imagine it did the same in your case!
The solution was, to not use the string type but the JSonType in the parmeter.
So I changed the interface to:

```
TServerMethods1.InsertMember(juserid, jPw, jMemberName, jPhoneNumber: TJSONString): TJsonArray;
```

But now the parameter are jsonobjects and needed special handling in case somebody left a parameter blank. For this I used local variables.
For every received parameter I did the following check and copied it to a local variable:

if not Assigned(jPhoneNumber) then
      PhoneNumber:= ''
   else
      PhoneNumber:= UpperCase(StringReplace(jPhoneNumber.ToString,'"','',[rfReplaceAll]));

After that it all worked.
In your case I think he converts t and f to a boolean value as he tried to make a number out of the phone number!
Since then I always use TJSonobjects.